# Advice "on" or advice "about"?

Tags: prepositions

I have an assignment, and its title would be...

ADVICE ON HOW AND NOT TO ACHIEVE YOUR DREAMS

**My question is...What's more accurate and appropriate to use here, "on" or "about"?**

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable with little difference in meaning. That's why the two may be interchangeable in conversational English.

The word combination *"advice on"* tends to *specifically* mean "give/provide advice", whereas *"advice about something"* seems to imply *you want to inform someone about something.*

Therefore, the former would be more accurately used.

Also, I would insert another "how" in "... how and **how not** to achieve ..."

Answer (score 1):

"Advice" is a mass noun (uncountable). We can refer to "advice" or "some advice". We never say *"advices".

If we want to make it countable, we can refer to "pieces of advice", but this is rarely necessary. Often a piece of advice seems to suggest advice that might be unwelcome ("let me give you a piece of advice" - alternatively "some advice"), whereas when requesting advice we would say "some advice" ("please could you give me some advice" - rarely "a piece of advice").

"Advice on" and "advice about" are both correct.

"How and not to achieve" is incorrect. You could say "how to achieve and how not to achieve your aims" or "how to achieve your aims and how not to" or simply "how to achieve your aims".

You don't usually "achieve" a dream. You can make a dream come true, or you can fulfil a dream.